# How to remove reference from Xcode after deleting file from library?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, uiwebview

Xcode is not allowing to upload app with deprecated webview API. So I have deleted this file from react-native to resolved this issue. But on build time it gives me below error. 
How can I solve this issue?
If I am removing any from the library, how to remove its reference from Xcode. I want to remove file reference using CLI or any custom command to do this.

```
The following build commands failed:
    PBXCp Views/RCTWebView.h /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/community_app-cldwyrbdtciuokgdmkewvkkfdofo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/community_app/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/include/React/RCTWebView.h
    PBXCp Views/RCTWebViewManager.h /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/community_app-cldwyrbdtciuokgdmkewvkkfdofo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/community_app/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/include/React/RCTWebViewManager.h
(2 failures)
```

Comment: cmnd+shift+k to  clean the project, then go to preference->Location, delete the DerivedData folder. Rerun and try!

Comment: Using GUI its working fine. But i want to achieve this using command line interface.

Answer (score 0):

Use the search at the bottom of the file browser window to find the files you removed. Any references whose files have been deleted should appear in red. Select them and hit delete. (WebView related files don't appear in my screenshot because I've already removed them.)

[image]

Comment: How can i do this using CLI?